# Openshift - redirect all https url to http

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

I want to disable all https request and I want to redirect all https request to http in openshift wordpress application.

I tried lots of code.

Nothing happened after this code.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I tried this below code too. But it shown me **redirecting loop** error.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I also tried by creating wordpress plugin. But this code also shown me **redirecting loop** error.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'hkp_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );

function hkp_ssl_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_ssl() && ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );
            exit();
        } else {
            wp_redirect( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried below code in .htaccess

Method 1.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
</IfModule>
```

Method 2.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

All above code has not working openshift wordpress. Can you please guide me how can I implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432809/htaccess-redirect-https-url-to-http. it should work.

Comment: Already tried this, Not worked